# follow-up on something

Tags: vocabulaire, québec, registre-familier

I want to say “follow up on something” in French, where the expression means to do something regarding something in the past, like a postponed task.

My dictionary gives the word “suite" for the noun “follow-up”, but there are many translations for the verb, like “*donner suite à quelque chose*” and others that don't sound right to me, like “*suivre*”. I think “*suivre*” is supposed to be the other meaning of “follow up” where it basically means the same as “to follow” or “to come after”.

What is the right way to say this in colloquial French? Is there a particular way to say it in Québécois French?

---

Je veux dire « *follow up on something* » en français. On parle de faire quelque chose à propos d'un sujet passé, comme une tâche reportée.

Mon dictionnaire donne la traduction « suite » pour le substantif « *follow-up* », mais il y a beaucoup de traduction pour le verbe, par exemple : « donner suite à quelque chose » et d'autres qui ne semblent pas correctes, comme « suivre ». Je crois que « suivre » est l'autre signification du verbe « *follow up* », où il a la même signification que « *to follow* » ou « *to come after* ».

Quelle est la formulation correcte en français courant ? Est-ce qu'il y a un moyen propre aux québécois-es ?

Comment: Pour la France, *En suivant quelque chose* ou *le suivi de qqch* devrait convenir. http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=follow+up+on+something vous donne des indications selon les conextes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are perfectly correct on all your assumptions:

- the follow-up = *le suivi*
- **to follow up on something = *donner suite à quelque chose*<sup>1</sup>**
- to follow (somebody) = *suivre (quelqu'un)*
- to come after (an event) = *suivre (un événement)*, *succéder à (un événement)* (more litt., probably not for all contexts)

---

Votre compréhension est juste :

- *the follow-up* = le suivi
- ***to follow up on something* = donner suite à quelque chose**
- *to follow (somebody)* = suivre (quelqu'un)
- *to come after (an event)* = suivre (un événement), succéder à (un événement) (plus litéraire, probablement pas adapté à tous les contextes)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Please note *quelque chose* is written without a dash.</sub>

<sub>This answers is for France. I'll leave it to someone from Québec to answer if the idioms are different for this translation.</sub>

Comment: Dans le domaine des affaires, dans la [correspondance](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=donner+suite&T3.x=0&T3.y=0), on fait peu dans le régionalisme à mon avis...

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer will change depending on the context and the timespan between the events :

- For "Following our meeting...', you would say : "Suite à notre réunion"
- For "As a follow-up of our meeting", you would say : "Pour donner suite à notre réunion" (you won't say : "Pour suivi de ...", even if it is grammatically correct)

The French verb "suivre" is the equivalent of the verb "to follow". The way you use the verb will change depending on the postposition you are using in the English version.

Answer (score 1):

I also regularly use "faire un suivi" for "to follow up".